# Extract text between two pieces of text

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, text-extraction

I'm trying to use Python to extract text between the below headers:

```
@HEADER1
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
@othertext
```

The exact text of `@HEADER1` + `@othertext` might change over time. So I need to to be dynamic.

Also, `HEADER2` is a word that starts with an `'@'`. So is there a `startswith` function I can use? Or a regular expression?

Something like.

```
For line in file:
    if(line == 'HEADER1'):
        print next line
        continue = TRUE
    if(continue == TRUE):
        print(line)
    elif(line == othertext):
        break
```

Comment: there's no `HEADER2` within your content

Comment: `line.startswith("@")` that will find your word that starts with @

Comment: do not do `if line == '@HEADER1'`, do `if line.startswith('@HEADER1')`. With the first option you are forgetting the newline character(s). And do not use `continue` which is a python built-in. Also `For` is spelled with a lowercase "f"

Comment: Shouldn't you take the `@` into account, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does the job

```
import re

string = """@HEADER1
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
@othertext"""

print '"{}"'.format(re.split(r'(@HEADER1[\n\r]|[\n\r]@othertext)', string)[2])
```

output:

```
"ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe"
```

Comment: does this work if the newline characters are `\r\n`?

Answer (score 2):

Looking something like this?

```
import re

string = """@HEADER1
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
@othertext
@HEADER2
ExtractMe2
ExtractMe2
ExtractMe2
ExtractMe2
ExtractMe2
ExtractMe2
ExtractMe2
ExtractMe2
ExtractMe2
@othertext"""

for a in re.findall(r'@\w+(?:\r\n|\r|\n)(.*?)@\w+(?:\r\n|\r|\n)?', string, re.DOTALL):
    print a
```

Output:

```
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe
ExtractMe

ExtractMe2
ExtractMe2
ExtractMe2
ExtractMe2
ExtractMe2
ExtractMe2
ExtractMe2
ExtractMe2
ExtractMe2
```

Answer (score 0):

Without re

```
string = """@HEADER1
    ExtractMe
    ExtractMe
    ExtractMe
    ExtractMe
    ExtractMe
    ExtractMe
    ExtractMe
    ExtractMe
    ExtractMe
    @othertext"""
```

You can play around with `str.find` inside a string splice. Like so:

```
print(string[string.find("\n"):string.find("\n@")])
```

Or you can turn the string into a list, get the elements you want and join it back together like so...

```
list = string.split("\n")
list = list[1:len(list)-1]
print("\n".join(list))
```

Answer (score 0):

I use in such occasions partition() method

```
text_to_extract = "@HEADER1\nExtractMe\nExtractMe\nExtractMe\nExtractMe\nExtractMe\nExtractMe\nExtractMe\nExtractMe\nExtractMe\n@othertext"
extracted = text_to_extract.partition('@HEADER1')[2].partition('@othertext')[0]
print (extracted)
```

Output:

```
ExtractMe  
ExtractMe  
ExtractMe  
ExtractMe  
ExtractMe  
ExtractMe
ExtractMe  
ExtractMe  
ExtractMe
```